# Вывести непарный элемент в числовом массиве

Tags: javascript

Суть задачи в вопросе. Решаю с применением операции XOR для обнуления парных элементов. Простым циклом сделалось очень быстро, но хочу разобраться как следует с перебирающими методами массивов, поэтому решил сделать через map. Думал, что выведется массив с нулями на месте парных элементов, и один мой непарный. Не получилось, прошу помощи.

```
function change(arr){
if(!arr || arr.length==0) return null;
 let result = arr[0];
let bufArr = arr.map(function(index,i,arr){
return result ^= index;},1);
return bufArr;
}
```

Comment: не дополниьте вопрос примером исходного массива и того, который вы ожидаете на выходе

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант. На выходе будет массив с неповторяющимися элементами.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,3,1,2];

const res = arr.filter((element, index, array) => {
  return arr.indexOf(element, index+1) === -1 &&
         arr.lastIndexOf(element, index-1) === -1;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
```

Comment: спасибо, возьму алгоритм на заметку. но хочу именно с xor и с применением перебирающего метода

Comment: map выполняет один проход по массиву, над каждым элементом массива выполняется функция, которая возвращает новое значение элемента массива. Чтобы использовать xor для обнуления нужно более одного прохода.